# C# Valid Combination counter before appending?

Tags: c#, file

H I'm making text combiner to combine from text files into one, I want to calculate how many lines will be combined before making the proccess
my original code to combine lines

```
foreach (var typeLine in File.ReadAllLines(path).ToArray())
   {
       foreach (var key in keywords)
       {
           foreach (var pt in pagetypes)
           {
               foreach (var pf in pageformats)
               {
                   foreach (var sf in searchFunctions)
                   {
                       var generateDork = typeLine.Replace("pt", pt) + typeLine.Replace("pf", pf) 
                                                                     + typeLine.Replace("sf", sf) + typeLine.Replace("kw", key);
                       geneneratedDorks.Append(generateDork);
                       dorkCounter++;
                       int sum = dorkCounter / 100;
                       Config.Title($"Costum Dork Gen | Formats Found: {formatCounter.ToString()} | Dorks Generated: {dorkCounter.ToString()} | Progress: {sum.ToString()}%");
                       geneneratedDorks = geneneratedDorks.Distinct().ToList();
                   }
               }
           }
       }
```

Any help Will be appreciate it

Comment: What's your problem / question?

Comment: Does every `typeLine` have strings "pt", "pf", "sf", and "kw"?

Comment: Yup all lines have it

Comment: My problem is how to calculate how many lines will be generated or something close to the number

Comment: Before generating

Comment: Why can't you simply generate the result, count the lines and then throw it away? For me it looks like `count = lines.distinct() * keywords.distinct() * pagetypes.distinct() * pageformats.distinct() * searchFunctions.distinct()` but why add an extra code path?

Comment: I need to calculate the lines before the result so I can write progressbar

Comment: Ok, so you don't need the number of lines in your result but the number of lines in your input file? ... then your progress bar would show something like "Processing {curLineNumber} of {totalInputLinesCount}"?